# clustering latent space of cnn lstm autoencoder

Tags: clustering

I am working on cnn-lstm autoencoder for anomaly detection in multivariate time series dataset. However, I need to cluster the latent space for fault diagnosis. But my latent space shape is in the form (n_obs, timestep, features), can anyone recommend a clustering algorithm that accepts this shape as input?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot reshape your 3-mode latent space tensor into a matrix?

Answer (score 0):

This paper may be useful for your use-case: https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2019/hash/1359aa933b48b754a2f54adb688bfa77-Abstract.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).